# mvc3 dropDownList Validation because of optionLabel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, drop-down-menu

```
@Html.DropDownList(
   "CreatedByUser_ID",
   new SelectList(
          Model.GetUsers(), 
          "ID", 
          "Name", 
          (int)Model.CreatedByUser_ID),
   "select one user----")
```

CreatedByUser_ID property on model has no Required attribute, but on client side the generated select box is validated. If I remove optionLabel (select one user----) then validation is turned off.

Why mvc3 automatically validate my dropdownbox without required field ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if your model property `CreatedByUser_ID` is an int, the HTML rendered by the helper will not specify a `value` attribute for the "select one user" option. You can't give an int a null value, so the validation kicks in.

Surely you would want the user to select an option? If not, try making your `CreatedByUser_ID` a nullable int - `int?` in C#.

Comment: Thanks. You are quick and correct. It was because of the reason you described. int? solved it.